# rfid module not working (rc522)

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

i brought a rfid module which is rc 522 but when i upload the code it is not reading the card  even when i upload example code i have returned it 2 times and got it replaced but the same problem may i know the solution

```
#include "SPI.h" // SPI library
#include "MFRC522.h" // RFID library (https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid)

const int pinRST = 9;
const int pinSDA = 10;

MFRC522 mfrc522(pinSDA, pinRST); // Set up mfrc522 on the Arduino

void setup() {
  SPI.begin(); // open SPI connection
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Initialize Proximity Coupling Device (PCD)
  Serial.begin(9600); // open serial connection
}

void loop() {
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { // (true, if RFID tag/card is present ) PICC = Proximity Integrated Circuit Card
    if(mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { // true, if RFID tag/card was read
      Serial.print("RFID TAG ID:");
      for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; ++i) { // read id (in parts)
        Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX); // print id as hex values
        Serial.print(" "); // add space between hex blocks to increase readability
      }
      Serial.println(); // Print out of id is complete.
    }
  }
}
```

this is one of the many codes i used

Comment: What gets printed? You have a lot of serial prints there, can you please edit the question and share what you see?

Comment: i just see nothing

Comment: Possibly you have wired it incorrectly. Without seeing any photos, links to the module you bought, or schematics, it is very hard, if not impossible, to say.

Comment: SDA                           10,
SCK                            13,
MOSI                      11,
MISO                     12,
IRQ                          UNUSED,
GND                      GND,
RST                                   9,
3.3V                                 3.3V,  i dont feel they are wrong